# reference to an array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, reference

Question is make an array of 10 integers that's fine

```
int array[10];
```

Now question is

how to make a `reference` to an `array` which I have declared above ?

I tried this

```
int &ra = a;
```

But it's giving me error... 
Please provide me details about this error and how to make `reference` of an `array`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
int (&ra)[10] = a;
```

Alternatively, you can use a `typedef` to separate this into the type for "array of 10 ints" and having a reference there-to, as in:

```
typedef int int10[10];
int10& my_ref = a;
```

The problem with your `int &ra = a;` is that it tells the compiler to create a reference of type `int` that refers to an `array of 10 ints`... they're just not the same thing.  Consider that `sizeof(int)` is a tenth of the size of an array of ten `int`s - they occupy different amounts of memory.  What you've asked for with the reference's type could be satisfied by a particular integer, as in `int& ra = a[0];`.

I appreciate it's a bit confusing that `int* p = a;` is allowed - for compatibility with the less type-safe C, pointers can be used to access single elements or arrays, despite not preserving any information about the array size.  That's one reason to prefer references - they add a little safety and functionality over pointers.

For examples of increased functionality, you can take `sizeof my_ref` and get the number of bytes in the `int` array (`10 * sizeof(int)`), whereas `sizeof p` would give you the size of the pointer (`sizeof(int*)`) and `sizeof *p == sizeof(int)`.  And you can have code like this that "captures" the array dimension for use within a function:

```
template <int N>
void f(int (&x)[N])
{
    std::cout << "I know this array has " << N << " elements\n";
}
```

Comment: @Toni D :It's only half of my answer... what about the error I got .. please clarify me

Comment: Later edit is fine... but when I try int &ra = a it's giving me compilation error: that non const int & cannot be assigned to rvlaue ....I am asking what's this

Comment: It's an unhelpful compiler error message. You shouldn't expect compiler error messages to always explain the error in terms you can understand. I think the compiler is trying to make your code work by creating a temporary, but then it sees you have `int&` not `const int&` and it knows you cannot bind a temporary to a non-const reference. So that is the error you get. Try changing `int&` to `const int&` and you'll see you get another error, perhaps a more helpful one (but perhaps not).

Comment: Yeah It's still giving error by changing it to const ..anyway thanx for expalnation.. going to accept your answer... :)

Comment: @Omkant: you can't bind a non-`const` reference to a `const` variable without using a `const_cast<>`.  That would defeat the protection `const` is designed to provide.  You can bind a `const` reference to a non-`const` variable though.

Answer (score 3):

The reference to array will have type `int (&a)[10]`.

```
int array[10];
int (&a)[10] = array;
```

Sometimes it might be useful to simplify things a little bit using `typedef`

```
typedef int (&ArrayRef)[10];
...
ArrayRef a = array;
```

Comment: Does that simplify anything? The typedef is as complex as the original reference declaration.

Comment: Yeah, but if you pass this array reference to functions frequently, it *might* be easier and more explicit to use a type alias for functions parameters. This is not so great compared to using typedef for function pointers though.

Comment: It might be even more handy to use a typedef for array (like in Tony's answer).

Answer (score 1):

This is a reference to an array of of ints of size 10:

```
int (&ra)[10];
```

so

```
int (&ra)[10] = a;
```

Comment: That's a reference to an int, you wanted a reference to an array.

Comment: @Omkant well, `int &ra` is a reference to an `int` for starters. Even after many years I still find some C declaration syntax confusing. I would use `std::array<int>` or `std::tr1::array<int>` instead.

Comment: My question is in this case when I try int &ra = a it's giving me compilation error: that non const int & cannot be assigned to rvlaue ....I am asking what's this .. ?

Answer (score 1):

You can typedef the array type (**the type should not be incomplete**) as follow:

```
#define LEN 10
typedef int (array)[LEN]; 

int main(void)
{
    array arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};    //define int arr[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    array arr2;                     //declare int arr[10];
    array *arrptr = &arr;           // pointer to array: int (*arrptr)[10] = &arr;
    array &&arrvef;                 // declare rvalue reference to array of 10 ints
    array &ref = arr;               // define reference to arr: int (&ref)[10] = arr;
}
```